# get column names of table vs determine column is primary key or not (sql)

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

i want to get all columns of table vs an extra column that determine field is Primary Key or not.i'm using this code:

```
SELECT c.column_id     ID,       c.name                   ItemName,
    CASE
        WHEN tblCon.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END                      ISPK
   FROM   sys.tables tb
   JOIN sys.columns c
        ON  tb.name = 'register'
        AND tb.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
   JOIN sys.types tp
        ON  c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
   LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc
        ON  c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id]
        AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K
        ON  c.name = k.COLUMN_NAME
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tblCon
        ON  tblCon.TABLE_NAME = 'register'
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

in this example tablename is "register".

this code is correct but for primary key field return two records:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG3EK.jpg)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added one more required column as details.

```
SELECT c.column_id ID,  c.name   ItemName,
    CASE
        WHEN tblCon.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END   ISPK,
      ISNULL(tblCon.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,'') as Detail

   FROM   sys.tables tb
   JOIN sys.columns c
        ON  tb.name = 'register'
        AND tb.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
   JOIN sys.types tp
        ON  c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
   LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc
        ON  c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id]
        AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
  LEFT JOIN (select * from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where  (CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' or CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'FK_%')  and TABLE_NAME='register') AS K
        ON  c.name = k.COLUMN_NAME
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  AS tblCon
        ON  tblCon.TABLE_NAME = 'register'
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT c.column_id  ID, c.name   ItemName,
    CASE
        WHEN tblCon.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END   ISPK
   FROM   sys.tables tb
   JOIN sys.columns c
        ON  tb.name = 'register'
        AND tb.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
   JOIN sys.types tp
        ON  c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
   LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc
        ON  c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id]
        AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
  LEFT JOIN (select * from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where  CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' and TABLE_NAME='register') AS K
        ON  c.name = k.COLUMN_NAME
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  AS tblCon
        ON  tblCon.TABLE_NAME = 'register'
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Comment: Condition for CONSTRAINT_NAME is missing in original query since KEY_COLUMN_USAGE considering Other Keys also.

Comment: If my answer is OK and can be accepted then kindly accept the answer...thanks

Comment: Excuse me..do you know if i want to add an other extra column that determine field is detail or not,what's to do ?

Comment: Can please let us know what do you exactly mean 'detail or not', any eaxmple of required output.

Comment: OK.Detail is same Foreign key.

Comment: Added an answer for it.please check.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer from Sagar and cleaning it up considerably. There were two extra joins, I change the subquery to a left join and modified some of the join conditions so the table name only need to be entered once.

```
SELECT c.column_id AS ID
    , c.name AS ItemName
    , CASE
        WHEN tblCon.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS ISPK
FROM sys.tables tb
JOIN sys.columns c ON 
    tb.object_id = c.object_id
    AND tb.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K on 
    CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' 
    and TABLE_NAME = tb.name
    AND c.name = k.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  AS tblCon ON 
    tblCon.TABLE_NAME = tb.name
    AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND tblCon.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where tb.name = 'register'
```